# Automatically answer to bash script openvpn command

Tags: bash, ssh, openvpn

I need to respond at 3 questions in a script :

- yes
- password*
- password*

This is the output when i use this command :
I don't want to use a specific other script just for this command.

`printf "yes\password*\npassword*\n" | docker-compose run --rm openvpn ovpn_revokeclient "ovpn-"$1 remove`

```
Please confirm you wish to revoke the certificate with the following subject:

subject=
    commonName                = ovpn-toto5


Type the word 'yes' to continue, or any other input to abort.
  Continue with revocation: Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/pki/easy-rsa-9.IlcpnJ/tmp.PKMKIm
Enter pass phrase for /etc/openvpn/pki/private/ca.key:
Revoking Certificate 6D9F08EFEB4D6A925969D8829F20A4C0.
Data Base Updated

IMPORTANT!!!

Revocation was successful. You must run gen-crl and upload a CRL to your
infrastructure in order to prevent the revoked cert from being accepted.


Generating the Certificate Revocation List :
Using SSL: openssl OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/pki/easy-rsa-47.nEJLBc/tmp.OeLpeI
Enter pass phrase for /etc/openvpn/pki/private/ca.key:
User interface error
139677322186056:error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:545:while reading strings
unable to load CA private key
139677322186056:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:583:
139677322186056:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:461:

Easy-RSA error:

CRL Generation failed.


ERROR: 1
```

I tried with echo too, but same problem..
I just don't understand how i can pass those values..
Thanks for help !

SEXPECT :

```
/usr/bin/sexpect spawn docker-compose run --rm openvpn easyrsa build-client-full "ovpn-toto" nopass
    out=$(sexpect expect_out)
    if [[ $out == "Enter pass phrase for /etc/openvpn/pki/private/ca.key:" ]]; then
        sexpect send -enter "mypassword*"
        continue
    fi
```

Comment: You probably should use `expect` program/language.

Comment: @AlexBaranowski If i have to use expect, i have to create another script... I would like to keep everything in one script

Comment: try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) which you can use to write *Expect* with shell code only.

Comment: for security reason well designed apps dont read passwords from stdin so usual `echo password | /some/app` does not work. this is when you have to use Expect-like tools unless the app has a special option to get the password in other way.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells I just installed your tool on my Debian10 system. Compilation ok, no errors. I have read your doc, but i'm a newbie, so if you know how to help me you can post your answer. I updated mine with what i tried

Comment: no idea how your tool works so cannot write the exact script for you. you better start with some simpler examples and see how these Expect-like tools work.